# ckeditor autocomplete plugin not working

Tags: php, autocomplete, ckeditor

I was using navalgandhi plugin http://navalgandhi1989.github.io/ckeditor-autocomplete-suggestions-plugin/  to get autocompletion in ckeditor , but when intgrating this , am getting the follwing error , pls help .

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'execCommand' of undefined ckeditor
```

But in localhost its wotking properly .

**ckeditor/config.js**

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2014, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'others' },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];


    config.extraPlugins = 'autocomplete';


    // Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
    // not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
    config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Set the most common block elements.
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
    config.fullpage=true;

    // Simplify the dialog windows.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';

};
```

**ckeditor/index.js**

```
var Index = {

    suggestions : [],

    init : function()
    {
        Index.bindEvents();
        //$('#getNewSuggestionsButton1').click();
               // Index.getSuggestionsFromServer('data/suggestions1.json');
                Index.getSuggestionsFromServer('notification/loadSuggestions');
        Index.initCkEditor();
    },

    bindEvents : function()
    {
        $('#getNewSuggestionsButton1').on('click', function()
        {
            Index.getSuggestionsFromServer('data/suggestions1.json');
        });

        $('#getNewSuggestionsButton2').on('click', function()
        {
            Index.getSuggestionsFromServer('data/suggestions2.json');
        });
    },

    initCkEditor : function()
    {
        //Here "CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 51" is the key combination for '#'
        $('textarea#ckeditorBox').ckeditor({ suggestionsTriggerKey: { keyCode: CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 51 }});
        CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
            //Here 'Index.suggestions' is the Array which is holding the current list of suggestions
            CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditorBox.execCommand('reloadSuggetionBox',Index.suggestions);
        });
    },

    getSuggestionsFromServer : function(url)
    {
        Index.suggestions = [];
        Index.ajaxCall(url,'',Index.getSuggestionsFromServerCallback);
    },

    getSuggestionsFromServerCallback : function(response)
    {

        var sugggestions = response.sugggestions;

        $.each(sugggestions, function(index,sugggestion)
        {
            Index.suggestions.push({
                            "id" : sugggestion.id,
                            "label" : sugggestion.label
                        });
        });
        CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditorBox.execCommand('reloadSuggetionBox',Index.suggestions);
    },

    ajaxCall : function(urlForAjax,dataForAjax,successCallBack)
    {
               $.getJSON('/notification/loadSuggestions')
                        .done(function (resp) { console.log(resp);
                            successCallBack(resp);
                        })
    }   
}
```

And in **ckeditor/plugins/autocomplete/plugin.js**

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('autocomplete',
            {
                init : function(editor) {

                     var autocompleteCommand = editor.addCommand('autocomplete', {
                        exec : function(editor) {
                              var dummyElement = editor.document
                                    .createElement('span');
                            editor.insertElement(dummyElement);

                            var x = 0;
                            var y = 0;

                            var obj = dummyElement.$;

                            while (obj.offsetParent) {
                                x += obj.offsetLeft;
                                y += obj.offsetTop;
                                obj = obj.offsetParent;
                            }
                            x += obj.offsetLeft;
                            y += obj.offsetTop;

                            dummyElement.remove();
                          editor.contextMenu.show(editor.document
                                    .getBody(), null, x, y);
                        }
                    });
                },
                afterInit : function(editor) {
                    editor.on('key', function(evt) {
                        if (evt.data.keyCode == CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 51) {
                            editor.execCommand('autocomplete');
                        }
                    });
                    var firstExecution = true;
                    var dataElement = {};

                     editor.addCommand('reloadSuggetionBox', {
                            exec : function(editor) {
                                if (editor.contextMenu) {
                                    dataElement = {};
                                    editor.addMenuGroup('suggestionBoxGroup');
                            var Suggestions = ['google', 'facebook', 'github', 'microsoft', 'yahoo'];
                            $.each(Suggestions,function(i, suggestion)
                            {
                                    var suggestionBoxItem = "suggestionBoxItem"+ i; 
                                    dataElement[suggestionBoxItem] = CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF;
                                    editor.addMenuItem(suggestionBoxItem,
                                                                        {
                                        id : suggestion.id,
                                        label : suggestion.label,
                                        group : 'suggestionBoxGroup',
                                        icon  : null,
                                        onClick : function() {
                                            var data = editor.getData();
                                            var selection = editor.getSelection();
                                            var element = selection.getStartElement();
                                            var ranges = selection.getRanges();
                                            ranges[0].setStart(element.getFirst(), 0);
                                            ranges[0].setEnd(element.getFirst(),0);
                                            editor.insertHtml(this.id + '&nbsp;');
                                            },
                                            });
                                    });

                                    if(firstExecution == true)
                                        {
                                            editor.contextMenu.addListener(function(element) {
                                                return dataElement;
                                            });
                                        firstExecution = false;
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                     });

                    delete editor._.menuItems.paste;
                },
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

because   console.log(CKEDITOR.instances) does not contain an instance named "ckeditorBox"

do this console.log(CKEDITOR.instances) and get the id of your editor that way

its probably editor1

CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditorBox.execCommand('reloadSuggetionBox',Index.suggestions);

should be changed to

CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.execCommand('reloadSuggetionBox',Index.suggestions);
 or
CKEDITOR.instances['editorId']execCommand('reloadSuggetionBox',Index.suggestions);